# How integration tests should be in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I want to write integration tests in nodejs and jest.

As far as I know, integration tests should interact with databases and third parties.

But *how* to write them?

- In jest?
- Do they write differently than unit tests?
- Do they have another extension in the files? or did they end up with `.spec.ts`?
- Do they need to be in special directories?
- Do I never create a stub/mock in those tests?

Answer (score 0):

1. Jest is just a library for writing tests. It does not care whether you write a unit or integration or system test inside its test blocks.
2. Normally you would need to add some extra steps for connecting to a database or clean the database before and after each or all of the tests in a test suite.
3. No. The extension is the same as unit tests.
4. Not necessarily, but personally I prefer to put them in a different folder from my unit tests. __ tests __/unit & __ tests __/integration
5. It depends on what kind of operation you are testing. So the answer would be No.